# DataGridView showing table from MS Access Database. How do I program save button in bindingNavigator1 to update database?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been googling this all day. I have a form that uses the database to autofill some of the fields, but the data in the database needs to be able to be updated periodically. The easiest way to do this for us is to allow user to update fields in datagridview. I just cannot find how to save changes to database. Thank you for in advance for any tips, I'm new to this so it's been alot of googling and this is the first issue I haven't been able to find any clear answers to.

````
    ```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Calculator
    {
        public partial class Database : Form
        {
            public Database()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Database_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 
    'tilesDataSet.Tiles_and_Quantities' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                
    this.tiles_and_QuantitiesTableAdapter.Fill(this.tilesDataSet.Tiles_and_Quantities);

            }

            private void runtimeCalculatorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                var form1 = new Form1();
                form1.Show();
            }

            private void standardCalculatorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                var form3 = new Form3();
                form3.Show();
            }

            private void savedResultsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                var form2 = new Form2();
                form2.Show();
            }

            private void tiles_and_QuantitiesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, 
    EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void tiles_and_QuantitiesDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    ```
````

I know there are many examples to this, but mostly using SQL, and I'm  using an Access database. There are still examples showing this but I am pretty green at this and am struggling to implement them. Currently, I'm trying:

````
    ```
     private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.Validate();
                    this.tiles_and_QuantitiesBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    this.tiles_and_QuantitiesTableAdapter.Update(this.tilesDataSet.Tiles_and_Quantities);
                    MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
    ```
````

and am getting an error CS1061 in .Update(). Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing that `this.tilesDataSet.Tiles_and_Quantities` is a DataTable ? If so then there are plenty examples on how to update changes from a DataTable into the database

Comment: I haven't found any that have helped me. Odds are I'm just not using them correctly, but any guidance would be great. If there is any info you need let me know please.